# Recyclerview in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using following code to create xml layout resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp48"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet"
        android:text="@string/select_a_folder"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerViewFolderList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFolderList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="350dp"
        android:maxHeight="350dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgViewClose2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/imgViewClose2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/close"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24dx"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerViewFolderList"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And when I load recyclerview with few items I'm getting expected output,

[image]

But if I load near 50 items, recyclerview fills the whole view, so my title and cancel button missing.

[image]

If I set the `layout_height="0dp"` for recyclerview, recyclerview totally gone like following.

[image]

I don't want to fix the size of recyclerview; if I fix it, it will work, but its always fixed, even if I pass only 2 items empty space will be there.

So I want the recyclerview should be wrap_content and also title and button should be visible.

Comment: Hi!, Why don't you use Alert Dialog for showing list instead? It looks much more beautiful.. Example: http://codesfor.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/list-dialog-169x300.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This simple change makes it works.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFolderList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgViewClose2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />
```

Thanks to all those who all tried to help me.

Comment: where is the change !?

Comment: @AhmedAdelIsmail Look, I changed `layout_height` from `wrap_content` to `0dp`, also I removed `maxHeight` & `layout_constraintHeight_max` attributes.

Comment: With this, the dialog does not collapse when the keyboard opens.

Comment: app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap" fixed the issue

Comment: best answer for this question

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue. Eventually I gave up on using ConstraintLayout here, and went back to RelativeLayout - easy and worked like a charm.

ConstraintLayout is great, but sometimes the best solution is old school.

Comment: Old school rocks

Answer (score 4):

After adding `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` in my recyclerView constraints started working

Answer (score 1):

use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/roundable_bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/wv_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bt_ok"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/ok" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `minWidth`, `minHeight` and `maxWidth`, `maxHeight` on the root layout of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In your Recyclerview

set

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

remove

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="350dp"
android:maxHeight="350dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to the `ConstraintLayout` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of the documentation `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` is deprecated. Use the below instead:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```